# NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element error filling user name using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I wish to enter username and password on the following site

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://baud.teamwork.com/launchpad/login?continue=%2Fcrm')
username = driver.find_element_by_id("loginemail")
username.send_keys("YourUsername")
```

I tried changing

```
driver.find_element_by_name
```

and still doesn´t work

I get the following error:

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"name","selector":"loginemail"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To send a *character sequence* within the `Email address` filed you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://baud.teamwork.com/launchpad/login?continue=%2Fcrm")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#loginemail"))).send_keys("lucas@stackoverflow.com")
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://baud.teamwork.com/launchpad/login?continue=%2Fcrm")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='loginemail']"))).send_keys("lucas@stackoverflow.com")
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports:

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: baud]

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions on [NoSuchElementException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993443/selenium-selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-when-using-chrome/47995294#47995294) in:

- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315587/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-una/50315715#50315715)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441658/selenium-in-python-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-unable-to/53442511#53442511)

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this:

```
username = driver.find_element_by_id("loginemail")
```

into this:

```
username = browser.find_element_by_id("loginemail")
```

Or the entire code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://baud.teamwork.com/launchpad/login?continue=%2Fcrm')
username = browser.find_element_by_id("loginemail")
username.send_keys("YourUsername")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Even if your locators correct selenium could not identify , because you need to wait for that element then only you can do some actions 

use this line before username locator line.(but thread sleep does not use nowadays because of time consuming ,if we use thread sleep (3000) our execution script line will delay for 3 sec )

    browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://baud.teamwork.com/launchpad/login?continue=%2Fcrm')
**Thread.sleep(3000);**
username = driver.find_element_by_id("loginemail")
username.send_keys("YourUsername")



Best way is please use Webdriver wait in selenium
```